# How do I remove my birthday from Skype for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipados, skype

A while ago I was fiddling with my birth date on Skype for iPad (version 8.68), and I accidentally pressed save.

However, I do not want it to be visible. I’ve tried changing my birth date to (day, month, year), but there aren’t any (day, month, year) buttons.

What are my options?

——EDIT——

(On Safari) I was able to see the option to change my birth date, however, it said it was a required field and I wasn’t able to change it.
Any suggestions?

Just making the year invisible would be great!

Comment: You can still change it to any other date if you don't want to make the real date publicly known

Answer (score 1):

If Skype saved that data to their servers, you would need to contact them or delete that account.

If it only saved to the Skype app, you might be able to delete the app and hope it clears on reinstall.

More specific guidance will be challenging to provide since we don’t know versions of the OS or App or even which country your account is managed. Most big companies handle accounts differently based on legal requirements and whether you disclose you are a minor or adult, etc...

Comment: @LittleKitten  For sure. I was seeing if there was an easy out here - http://www.skype.com/go/privacy. doesn’t look easy at all..... also I should have said earlier Welcome to Ask Different.